# Hyperledger fabric v1.0: multiple orderers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm currently working on a POC using hyperledger fabric + composer. I am somewhat confused when it gets to the consensus mechanism between orderers. From what i understand reading the documentation, hyperledger currently only supports SOLO and KAFKA. My understanding of SOLO is that the network only exists out of a single ordering node and no network consensus is reached between orderers (only 1 exists).

But this doesn't make sense to me; my gut tells me it must be possible to add multiple orderers without the use of KAFA / Zookeeper and that hyperledger has another mechanism to reach consensus between these two. The documentation regarding this is somewhat spotty and all over the place if i try to google it so i'm hoping someone can shed some light on the matter.

If no consensus mechanism exists between orderes besides a centralised one then what is the point of a distributed ledger platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary usage of SOLO ordering is for development mode, where you would like to test functionality without a need to span complex distributed consensus solutions. Moreover, note that consensus is a pluggable mechanism and could be replaced with anything you'd like, for example there is a recent proposal to use [SmartBFT](https://lists.hyperledger.org/pipermail/hyperledger-fabric/2017-September/001779.html) as an additional ordering service. Very similar to this you can add consensus mechanism of your own.

Currently if you need to distributed and highly available solutions for consensus there is a KAFKA based ordering service.

Comment: So it's not possible to currently set up multiple orderes without KAFKA, other than writing my own or waiting for SmartBF?

Comment: Currently there the only supported orderers are Kafka or Solo.

Answer (score 0):

The Raft-based consensus protocol was added in Hyperledger Fabric v1.4.1, which simplifies deployment and adds decentralization to OSNs. It removes the additional dependency of Kafka/ZooKeeper needed to run a fault-tolerant network.